# VBA change cell's value if it has a user defined style

Tags: vba, excel, stylesheet

I want to change all cells in Excel spreadsheet of specific, user defined style (let's say 'Beauty' style) to value "Beast".

`Sub BulkChangeValeOfStyle()
    Dim TheCell As Range
    For Each TheCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If TheCell.Style = "Beauty" Then
            TheCell.Value = "Beast"
        End If
    Next
End Sub`

This code is too slow. I got lots of those Beauty cells scattered round the spreadsheet. Is it possible to make it like this:

```
ActiveSheet.AllCellsWithaStyle="Beauty".value="Beast"
```

**Update**
This is just an idea:
`ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameFormatConditions).Activate`
or alternatively 
`ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameValidation).Activate`

but I do not know how to set up the criteria which determine `xlCellTypeSameFormatConditions`. Or criteria for `xlCellTypeSameValidation`. Anybody knows?

Comment: Please comment `TheCell.Value = "Beast"` out and tell us if this makes much difference in the time it takes. Thus we learn if it is the search or the update that takes so much time.

Comment: I can't give you any better advice then to limit the range where you search for this style.

Comment: Try setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with a better solution than your `For Each` loop. But you should create a new Style for the cells you want to modify, and modify the format properties of that style when needed like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Styles.Item("Good").Interior.ColorIndex=4
```